# C# Convert array to string and

Tags: c#

i'm new here and i want to convert array to string and result be like this  `'value1','value2','value3'` not like this `value1,value2,value31`.

Thanks.

```
string data;

data.Join(",", Client);

console.writeline(data);
//it give me result like this: value1,value2,value3 
//but i need to be like this 'value1','value2','value3'
```

Comment: you tried to compile with the same given code?

Answer (score 3):

```
String.Join(",", Client.Select(x => "'" + x + "'"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put an apostrophe before the first item, after the last item, and around the comma that separates them:

```
string data = "'" + String.Join("','", Client) + "'";
```

Edit: Just to edit

Comment: @EZI: Why do you think that? Where do you think that the apostrophes in the string `"','"` would go?

Comment: @codenheim You are right, but I can't undo my -1 unless answer is edited.